# Infinite Loop when checking conditions c++ !cin

Tags: c++

I'm basically expecting a number as input. The magnitude is negligible now as I know my else if loop works fine. But testing if its a number proves to be a bit trickier. I just want to call the function again and start over if the user enters in something alphanumeric or just plain words. Or pressed enter. Something that is not a number. I tried !cin since I am inputting into `int numTemp`, but that just results in an infinite loop that spills out `"what is the bitrate"` countless times. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I tried putting `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore(100, "\n")` inside the first if statement but to no avail. Thanks in advance.

```
bool iTunes::setBitRate()
{
cout << "What is the bitrate? ";
int numTemp;
cin >> numTemp;
if (!cin)
{
    cout << "WRONG" << endl;
    setBitRate();
}
else if( numTemp < MIN_BITRATE || numTemp > MAX_BITRATE)
{
    cout << "Bit Rate out of range" << endl;
    setBitRate();
}
else
{
    bitRate = numTemp;
}
}
```

Comment: IMHO it's questionable if recursive call is a good idea for doing this, I'd prefer looping to read in the value.

Comment: You would need both `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore` to remove non-digits from the input. Otherwise each successive input will fail, all for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read a string from the user instead of an int, and then check it and prompt for new input if you don't like the string (e.g. if it doesn't cleanly convert to a number, which you can check with `strtol`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the input is a number or character, you can use `isdigit`, but you have to pass it a `char` and then when it is a digit you can convert it to a `int` with `atoi`.

Answer (score 0):

When the statement `cin >> numTemp` fails due to non-numeric input the character causing the failure is **NOT** removed from the input stream. So the next time the stream extraction operator is called it will see the same non-numeric input as the last time. To avoid this you need to skip the existing input.

One way of doing this is to use `getline()` to read a complete line of text before trying to converting it to and integer. The folllowing code snippet illustrates this:

```
#include <cstdlib>

bool getint(istream& in, int & out) {
    string line;
    getline(in, line);
    char* endptr;
    out = strtol(line.c_str(), &endptr, 10);
    return endptr!=line.c_str();
}

bool iTunes::setBitRate()
{
    cout << "What is the bitrate? ";
    int numTemp;
    if ( !getint(cin, numTemp) && cin )
    {
        cout << "WRONG" << endl;
        setBitRate();
    }
    else if( numTemp < MIN_BITRATE || numTemp > MAX_BITRATE)
    {
        cout << "Bit Rate out of range" << endl;
        setBitRate();
    }
    else
    {
        bitRate = numTemp;
    }
}
```

NOTE: You should also check the status of cin after each read to ensure that some error has not occurred.

Answer (score -2):

i think this will helps

```
bool iTunes::setBitRate()
{
  cout << "What is the bitrate? ";
  int numTemp = 0;
  cin >> numTemp;
  if (!numTemp)
  {
    cout << "WRONG" << endl;
    setBitRate();
  }
  else if( numTemp < MIN_BITRATE || numTemp > MAX_BITRATE)
  {
    cout << "Bit Rate out of range" << endl;
    setBitRate();
  }
  else
  {
     bitRate = numTemp;
  }
 }
```

Comment: I think this invokes undefined behavior, as you're testing the value of numTemp which may not be initialized in the error case.